# Need help on Region based automation in sikuli

Tags: sikuli

Can anyone help me on how to test using "Regions" in sikuli automation tool (i.e) how to use a region, where to use etc..

If there is tutorial (or) video link that would be gr8..if anybody has an webinar session that covers the entire programming stuffs in sikuli, then that would be useful.

Thanks,
V.Prashanth

Comment: This doesn't belong on StackOverflow. [Take a look at this.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261845/1447173)

Answer (score 1):

All documentation that you require for using 'Region' in SikuliX is found here -
http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html

There is a launchpad site for SikuliX where you can read existing queries/ post your queries - 
https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli